# How to delete specific data in a pivot table?

Tags: excel

I need to delete a row in my raw data that is now obsolete, but I can't do it because whenever I try to delete the row, it gives me '' you cannot change part of an array ''.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your data in a table format? We need more information before we can really help. What that could mean is there is an Array Formula that you can't delete only one part of it. Look for a formula with { } surrounding it.

Comment: This is my formula {=VLOOKUP(B2:B198;J1:K6;2;1)} , the data is not in a table but 4 colums side by side. @MarkS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is there is an Array Formula within the row you are trying to delete.

1. Find the Array formula by looking for the column that has a formula that is surrounded with { }.
2. Once you find this array formula, highlight the entire range this formula is within and take note what area it covers.
3. Hit `F2` Then `CTRL + Enter` - this will break the array so expect errors.
4. Delete the row in question
5. Highlight the new array area and go into the formula bar then hit `CTRL + Shift + Enter` - This will replace the array formula as it was.

Comment: it worked, but my graph that is related to the pivot table isnt updating. When I try to update i get this error : the name of the pivot table isnt valid